Substitute substring with multiple characters
I am trying to make a string replacement using regex, but I am not able to achieve the expected result.
I have a list of strings ['INSUTRIN 150G','NEUROZINE 30 ML','INSULITROL 30 CAPS'] for example. I would like to transform this into:
['INSUTRIN','NEUROZINE','INSULITROL']
I tried the following approach using regex:
import re
def modify_string(x):
        return re.sub("\d{1,}\s{0,}[[ML]|G|KG|CAPS]", "", x).strip()

and get the results:
['INSUTRIN','NEUROZINE L','INSULITROL APS']
How could I set regex properly for that?

I'd try with r"\s*\d+\s*(?:ML|G|KG|CAPS)$" to get the spaces

re.sub(r'\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*(?:M?L|K?G|CAPS)', '', x) - demo

Also, maybe just return re.sub(r'\s+\d.*', '', x) will be enough (remove all from the first whitespace + digit occurrence).

Not an answer to your question, precisely, so I will limit this to the comments. But: would result = [s.split(" ")[0] for s in list_of_strings] be a solution to your problem? This uses basic python string manipulation and list comprehension syntax to extract the first word from each element in your list_of_strings.

Can you explain why you're taking any kind of replacement approach when, apparently, all you need is the first whitespace delimited token from each string? Maybe the sample input/output you've shown isn't as comprehensive as it might be

Since nobody bothered to explain your mistake to you: square brackets [ and ] are used to delimit character classes. [CAPS] means "one of the letters C, A, P, or S" and will not match the string "CAPS".

In addition, {1,} can be replaced by + and {0,} by *. Both methods are valid, but using + and * is more common.

If all you want is to remove the number and unit part in the end, then you can simply replace \s\d+.* for each string:
import re

def modify_string(x):
    return re.sub(r"\s\d+.*", "", x).strip()

things = ['INSUTRIN 150G', 'NEUROZINE 30 ML', 'INSULITROL 30 CAPS']
things = list(map(modify_string, things))
print(things)

Output:
['INSUTRIN', 'NEUROZINE', 'INSULITROL']

Additionaly:

If words have no spaces, you can simplify your function like this without using regex:

def modify_string(x):
    return x.split()[0]


If items should end with one of ML,G,KG,CAPS then:

def modify_string(x):
    return re.sub(r"\s\d+.*(ML|G|KG|CAPS)", "", x).strip()


import re

def modify_string(x):
    # Use regex to match numbers followed by optional space and the units
    return re.sub(r"\d+\s*(ML|G|KG|CAPS)", "", x).strip()

# Test your list of strings
strings = ['INSUTRIN 150G', 'NEUROZINE 30 ML', 'INSULITROL 30 CAPS']
modified_strings = [modify_string(s) for s in strings]

print(modified_strings)

